# vuejs dev build with dynamic output (files updated after every change) for docker

Tags: docker, vue.js

I do development on mac but would like to review changes in my VueJS project trough ubuntu docker container that runs Apache. Docker container uses mapped vuejs dist directory as a root.

When I do "vue-cli-service serve" it renders the app pages storing them into memory and obviously docker container has no access to it.

When I do "vue-cli-service build" it stores files in "/dist" folder but it takes forever to rebuild everything and it is not reactive to frequent code changes.

So long story short.

How to make VueJS run a background server (with and without HTTP server) to reactively change dist directory after every modification of the code. This way my docker container could render it trough Apache ?